# Segfault while implementing a primitive hashing function in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am trying to integrate a rather primitive "hashing" function. I know it's not cryptographically secure, it's just for learning...

It compiles but it segfaults everytime...

I put the first argument as the input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned int hash_pw(const char* p) {
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int res = 0;

    for(i = 50; i > 45; i--) {
        res += p[i] * (50 - i);
    }

    return res;
}

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) 
{
int asd = (int) malloc(50*sizeof(int));
asd = (unsigned int) hash_pw(argv[1]);
printf("%s\n", asd);
free(asd);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i = 50; p[i];` for an array with 50 elements is an immediate out of bounds access. Edit: actually, `p` isn't even the 50 element array. Its a CLI argument. What makes you certain that `argv[1]` will have at least 51 characters?

Comment: Should I change it to 52 then to accumulate for the null terminator?

Comment: I'm not sure what to do exactly

Comment: @SirMuffington *"I'm not sure what to do exactly"* I would start from the book as you completely do not understand what is going on. I normally would not comment this way but you cant program without understanding the basics.

Comment: What do the numbers 50, or 45, or 52 mean? Where did you get these numbers from?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You conpute an integer hash value of some characters that may or may not be valid (depending on how long the argument is), but then you use that value as a pointer, which unsuprisingly crashes.

Comment: I am trying to do a "hash check", which is more like a summing up of the ASCII table numbers, only a certain combination makes up a password. The idea might be rubbish, I'm just trying stuff out. @0___________ I have a C programming certificate, I just forgot some of the basics

Comment: @SirMuffington  some .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main issues:

1.

```
int asd = (int) malloc(50*sizeof(int));
asd = (unsigned int) hash_pw(argv[1]);
printf("%s\n", asd);
free(asd);
```

`asd` is an integer. You try to use it as a pointer in the "printf" function. call to the malloc makes no sense at all as you assign the pointer to the `int`. Call to free is also invalid

2. `for(i = 50;` your string might not be 51+ char long and it may invoke undefined Behaviour

**READ THE WARNINGS** **DO NOT SILENCE THEM**

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:21:11: warning: initialization of 'int' from 'void *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   21 | int asd = malloc(50*sizeof(int));
      |           ^~~~~~
<source>:23:10: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
   23 | printf("%s\n", asd);
      |         ~^     ~~~
      |          |     |
      |          |     int
      |          char *
      |         %d
<source>:24:6: warning: passing argument 1 of 'free' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   24 | free(asd);
      |      ^~~
      |      |
      |      int
In file included from <source>:5:
/opt/compiler-explorer/arm/gcc-arm-none-eabi-11.2-2022.02/arm-none-eabi/include/stdlib.h:94:15: note: expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'int'
   94 | void    free (void *) _NOTHROW;
      |               ^~~~~~
<source>:19:15: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
   19 | int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
      |           ~~~~^~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some error at this code (I'm not considering its logic).

- The malloc function, returns a pointer, in this case an 'int*'.
- To return as filled vector (by the hash function), i usually put a pointer argument, in this case I would probably do this 'int hash_pw(int **asd, const char *p)'. Then the function call could be:

```
int *asd = (int*) malloc(50*sizeof(int));
int ret = hash_pw(&asd, argv[1);
```

Note: you would take care with 'for' limits, at code the for starts with 'i=50', but the 'asd' vector can only be indexed between 0-49. I would probably do the 'has_pw' function like this

```
int hash_pw(int **asd, int max, const char* p) {
    for (int i = max -1 ; ....
        asd[i] = ....
}
```

But if you want to return a 'hash sum' how in the original for logic, you can do some like this:

```
unsigned int hash_pw(unsigned int max, const char* p) {
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int res = 0;

    for(i = max-1; i > 45; i--) {
        res += p[i] * (max - i);
    }

    return res;
}

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) 
{
  
    unsigned int asd;
    asd = hash_pw(50, argv[1]); // note: the max arg would be argc, or not?
    printf("%d\n", asd);
    
    return 0;
}
```